# how to hide view appear on top of previous selected row on click of another row inside GridView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gridview

I have a `Fragment` with custom `Adapter` extending `BaseAdapter` that manages a `GridView`.

I want to show images on each row of the `GridView` and `onClick` of each cell, I want to open a translucent view on top of that particular image which will show image details.

**Problem** is that when I click on the image, a translucent view opened on top of the image but when I click on next image then a translucent view opened on previous images is not hiding,it still appears over the first images..

[image: I want something like this screen...]

See the following code

**My Fragment**

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {

    String ss = null;
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<ProductParameterBO> productlist;
    GridViewCustomAdapter gridViewCustomAdapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_catalog_item,null);

            TextView configure = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_conf);

            configure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SplitViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("firstTab","1stTabs");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            TextView text_here = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_here);
            text_here.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditUploadActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            return rootView;
        } else {
            View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product,null);

            gridView =(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

            productlist = new ArrayList<ProductParameterBO>();

            productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Type","Numeric","yes","yes"));
            productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Typess","Numericss","yesss","yesss"));
            productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Typess","Numericss","yesss","yesss"));
            productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Typess","Numericss","yesss","yesss"));
            gridViewCustomAdapter = new GridViewCustomAdapter(getActivity(),productlist);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewCustomAdapter);
            gridViewCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return rootView;
        }

        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product,null);
    }
}
```

**My Adater**

```
public class GridViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<ProductParameterBO> availList;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    Context context;

    public GridViewCustomAdapter(Context ctx,List<ProductParameterBO> list){
        this.context = ctx;
        this.availList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return availList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return availList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        ProductParameterBO c = availList.get(position);
        // long id = c.getTimeId();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        final TeeTimeHolder holder;

        if (row == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row,parent,false);
            holder = new TeeTimeHolder();
            holder.myImage =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            holder.name =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView47);
            holder.edit =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
            holder.rl =(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.img_ovrly);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder =(TeeTimeHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(availList.get(position).getParameterName());
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.toi);
        holder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View rows = null;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_overlay,parent,false);
                // holder.rl = (RelativeLayout)rows.findViewById(R.id.img_ovrly);
                holder.rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    static class TeeTimeHolder {
        ImageView myImage;

        TextView name,edit;

        RelativeLayout rl;

        //TextView descriptions;

        /*  TextView coursefee;

        TextView viewdetils;*/
    }
}
```

**My XML layout grid_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:src="@drawable/toi"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Image Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView47"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/textView49"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView47"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img_ovrly"
        android:background="@color/opacity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mail"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_i"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title :"
            android:id="@+id/text_ttle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_i"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_ttle"
            android:text="hmmmm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_i"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#6ec6c5"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dimensions :"
            android:id="@+id/text_dimen"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_ttle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_dimen"
            android:text="32*23"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_ttle"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6ec6c5"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price :"
            android:id="@+id/text_prce"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_dimen"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_prce"
            android:text="32*23"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_dimen"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6ec6c5"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Color :"
            android:id="@+id/text_clr"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_prce"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_clr"
            android:text="red,white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_prce"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6ec6c5"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Min. Quantity :"
            android:id="@+id/text_minq"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_clr"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_minq"
            android:text="1000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_clr"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6ec6c5"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type :"
            android:id="@+id/text_typ"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_minq"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_typ"
            android:text="creamic"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_minq"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#6ec6c5"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img_flp"
            android:background="@drawable/flip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_typ"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I missing something? kindly help me to resolve this issue. I want a screen something like that. Am I doing right to open tranlucent screen on top of image and how to hide or make visivility gone on click of other images inside my Adater class.Any help would be appreciated in advanced

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things.

### 1. Use a flag

---

***NOTE this code is untested.***

You can create an encapsulated flag in your `ProductParameterBO` object to determine the visibility of your overlay view. Something like the following

```
boolean mInformationViewVisible = false;

public void setInformationViewVisible(boolean visible) {
    mInformationViewVisible = visible;
}

public boolean isInformationViewVisible() {
    return mInformationViewVisible;
}
```

Then use that in your `getView` method to set the visibility of the view.

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position,View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
    ...

    holder.myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int itemPosition = 0; itemPosition < availList.size(); itemPosition++) {
                if(itemPosition != position){
                    availList.get(itemPosition)
                        .setInformationViewVisible(false);
            }

            availList.get(itemPosition).setInformationViewVisible(true);
        }
    });

    if (currentItem.isInformationViewVisible()) {
        holder.rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    ...
}
```

### 2. Switch to RecyclerView

---

The second and better option is to switch to `RecyclerView`. This view is specifically built for individual interaction with items in your `Adapter`. It gives you more power over the `View` in terms of animations and removal/adittion of items to the adapter. You can read more on it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/).

It is very likely that the app in the image you attached is using `RecyclerView` to manage their content. The code to manage the selected info view will be very similar in `RecyclerView` to what I posted for the `ListView`, the only difference would be that you would pass the `OnClickListener` to the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and set it to the info view in there in stead of in the `getView()` method. I highly recommend using this approach as it will benefit you in the future of your app.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. but console always goes into else condition where  holder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE); has been written

Comment: when i clicked on image it show the overlay screen but when i clicked next image ,previous overlay screen still showing its not hiding

Comment: hi Neil,is there any way to get previous selected items in android gridview?

Answer (score 0):

In ProductParameterBO, you can keep a boolean member variable, and in getView() and if one image is clicked, you can set the boolean variables from that list as false, except the one you clicked. If the variable is true, it will display the image details, and if the variable is false, you can set the visibillty of the translucent view as Invisible of that particular position.

```
        @Override 
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
      final TeeTimeHolder holder;
        if (row == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row,parent,false);
            holder = new TeeTimeHolder();
            holder.myImage =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            holder.name =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView47);
            holder.edit =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
            holder.rl =(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.img_ovrly);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else { 
            holder =(TeeTimeHolder)row.getTag();
        } 


        holder.name.setText(availList.get(position).getParameterName());
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.toi);
        holder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View rows = null;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_overlay,parent,false);
               // holder.rl = (RelativeLayout)rows.findViewById(R.id.img_ovrly); 
               // holder.rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       for(int i=0;i<availList.size();i++){
            if(i!=position){
       availList.get(i).flag=false;
             }
          }
  availList.get(position).flag=true;

        } 
    }); 

    if(availList.get(i).flag){
      holder.rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
      holder.rl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response Arjun .. i am applying your concept let see..then back to u

Comment: hi Arjun, i tried your changes but now on click event ,translucent view is not open at all

Comment: Did you set the variable true in onClick()..I didn't mention it there

Comment: i have made the change!

Comment: how can i hide the view when clicked on next images... its not working yet